# Request.IsAuthenticated is alway false in OpenId Connect

Tags: openid-connect, sso

I have a requirement where the public users will click on login then it will go to SSO and after that it will redirect back to the website with details. I am using the OpenID connector for public user SSO for this I have created `Startup` file.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           CorePipeline.Run("initializeOwinMiddlewareCustom", new InitializeOwinMiddlewareArgs(app));
        }
    }
```

and below is `InitializeOwinMiddlewareCustom` class.

```
    public void Process(InitializeOwinMiddlewareArgs args)
    {
         args.App.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
         args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
         args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
               new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   Authority = authority,
                   ClientId = clientId,
                   ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                   ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
                   RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                   PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                   Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                   SaveTokens = true,
                   TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = false 
                   },
                   Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                   {
                       AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                       SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                       {
                           notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("surname", notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "surname").Value));
                           notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", notification.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                           notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("phone_number", notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "phone_number").Value));
                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                   }
               }
           );
        }
```

Login Controller:

```
  if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
       HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
  }
```

I am getting all claim in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`but in controller`Request.IsAuthenticated` is coming false.

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var claims= ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Claims.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using OpenID Connect, but this implementation seems different form the Sitecore docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-federated-authentication.html

I have also written a blogpost about it: https://www.jeroenbreuer.nl/blog/custom-identity-provider-in-sitecore/

Here are the important files:

**ProjectIdentityProvider.cs**

```
public class ProjectIdentityProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    private readonly IUrlUtils urlUtils;

    private readonly ICookieManager cookieManager;

    public ProjectIdentityProvider(
        IConfigurationRepository configurationRepository,
        IUrlUtils urlUtils,
        FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
        ICookieManager cookieManager,
        BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
    {
        this.configurationRepository = configurationRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configurationRepository));
        this.urlUtils = urlUtils ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urlUtils));
        this.cookieManager = cookieManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cookieManager));
    }

    protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
    {
        var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
        var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
        var saveSigninToken = identityProvider.TriggerExternalSignOut;

        var oidcOptions = this.SetupOidcOptions(authenticationType, saveSigninToken);

        args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
    }

    public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SetupOidcOptions(
        string authenticationType,
        bool saveSigninToken)
    {
        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            MetadataAddress = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(Constants.Settings.IdentityAccessManagementMetadataAddress),
            ClientId = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(Constants.Settings.IdentityAccessManagementClientId),
            ClientSecret = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(Constants.Settings.IdentityAccessManagementClientSecret),
            ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            RedeemCode = true,
            Scope = OpenIdConnect.ProjectIdentityScope,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync
            },
            TokenValidationParameters =
            {
                SaveSigninToken = saveSigninToken
            },
            CookieManager = cookieManager
        };

        return oidcOptions;
    }

    protected override string IdentityProviderName => OpenIdConnect.ProjectIdentityProvider;

    protected BaseLog Log { get; }

    public Collection<string> Scopes { get; } = new Collection<string>();

    private Task RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync(
        RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>
            notification)
    {
        var domain = urlUtils.GetDomain();
        var owinContext = notification.OwinContext;
        var protocolMessage = notification.ProtocolMessage;

        if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
        {
            var redirectUri = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(Constants.OpenIdConnectOptions.RedirectUri);
            // Make sure the redirectUri goes to the current domain. 
            redirectUri = WebUtil.GetUri(redirectUri, new Uri(domain)).ToString();
            protocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        }

        if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
        {
            var postLogoutRedirectUri = this.configurationRepository.GetSetting(Constants.OpenIdConnectOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
            // Make sure the postLogoutRedirectUri goes to the current domain.
            postLogoutRedirectUri = WebUtil.GetUri(postLogoutRedirectUri, new Uri(domain)).ToString();
            protocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
            protocolMessage.IdTokenHint = this.GetIdTokenHint(owinContext);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task SecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
        var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

        foreach (var current in identityProvider.Transformations)
        {
            current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**patch.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
                <mapEntry name="sites with extranet domain" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:instead="*[@name='sites with extranet domain']">
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>project</site>
                    </sites>
                    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='ProjectIdentityProvider']" />
                    </identityProviders>
                    <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <IsPersistentUser>false</IsPersistentUser>
                    </externalUserBuilder>
                </mapEntry>
            </identityProvidersPerSites>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="ProjectIdentityProvider" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                    <caption>Go to login</caption>
                    <domain>extranet</domain>
                    <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
                    <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
                    <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                        <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
                        <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                        <!-- If external authentication is configured with "TokenValidationParameters = {SaveSigninToken = true}", this saves the value from "claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext" to the "id_token" claim. -->
                        <transformation name="set id_token claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SaveIdTokenInClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                    </transformations>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
        </federatedAuthentication>
        <pipelines>
            <owin.identityProviders>
                <processor type="Project.Foundation.Identity.IdentityProviders.ProjectIdentityProvider, Project.Foundation.Identity" resolve="true" id="ProjectIdentityProvider">
                    <scopes hint="list">
                        <scope name="openid">openid</scope>
                        <scope name="sitecore.profile">sitecore.profile</scope>
                    </scopes>
                </processor>
            </owin.identityProviders>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**site.config**

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
      inherits="website"
      name="project"
      language="nl-NL"
      contentLanguage="nl-NL"
      scheme="https"
      rootPath="/sitecore/content/Project"
      startItem="/Home"
      loginPage="$(loginPath)project/ProjectIdentityProvider" />
```

If you use the Federated Authentication functionality provided by Sitecore you should also get the correct value in `Request.IsAuthenticated`. So it will be `true` if you are logged in.

Comment: I just found this blog which explains it really well: https://rmcdigital.com/sitecore/sitecore-single-sign-on-federated-authentication-with-azure-ad/

Comment: I do not want to protect all pages behind a login, I want to make a few pages be authorized. If I am adding [Authorize] then after SSO it is redirecting again to protect page and then again going to SSO means looping is going on. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to add the [Authorize] attribute. I don't know where you place this, but you can protect pages using the Sitecore security editor: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/assign-access-rights-to-a-security-account.html



If a page requires login for a certain role you should be redirected to the identity provider. If you are logged in and you have the correct role you should see the page and not be redirected.

Comment: How I can redirect the user to the identity server if the user tries to hit the supposed profile page?

Comment: That should happen automatically. If a user visits a page which he doesn't have access to the user should be redirected to the identity provider. See my site.config example from my original answer. The loginPage element is where you configure the identity provider it should redirect to.